# JS/Webpack : Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm curently building a React JS app and I've this error when I go on the '/' of my project :
**"Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element."**

In my project I've some components and few pages, and when I run my server with "npm start" I can't access to my main page.

My app was build without webpack, I added it after all my components were done.
**webpack.config.js** :

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
},
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test:  /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader',
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader',
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

};

**index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>React 101</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="app"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**.babelrc** :

```
{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}
```

**main.js** :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

*index.js :*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import '../src/assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css';
import '../src/assets/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 );
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('root')` will be `null` as you have no element with that ID in your `index.html`. And I have no idea why you call `ReactDOM.render` in two different files - if you have a whole app built in React, you should only be using this once, in your app's entry point. (Which ironically is typically called either `index.js` or `main.js`.)

Comment: Yeah get rid of `main.js` and and change `document.getElementById('root')` to `document.getElementById('app')` in` index.js`

Comment: Indeed, by replacing document.getElementById('root') by document.getElementById('app') it works ! Thanks !